# MySQL server is not responding

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I have `easyphp` installed in Windows server 2012, when I want to access to `phpmyadmin` on this server I type :

```
http://192.168.75.100/modules/phpmyadmin3522x160307103707/
```

It was running before, but today I got this error message :

> 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's
>   socket is not correctly configured)

I looked for a similar problem in stackoverflow and all I can find is to check if MySQL running on port 3306, and as you can see its up and running :

[image]

Another solution was to check if mysqld.exe is running, and as you can see its running :

[image]

I found another solution which says:

> mysql default port is 3306 can you try putting it and then try

and this is my config file :

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = "${path}/mysql/mysql.sock"

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port        = 3306

#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="${path}/mysql/"

#Path to the database root
datadir="${path}/mysql/data/"

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine = INNODB

# bind-address = 192.168.75.100
socket      = "${path}/mysql/mysql.sock"
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M


# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1


# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\\mysql\\data\\
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\\mysql\\data\\
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

## Edit :

this is the error file :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/it9cvsutxldebyi/WIN-BQ33O4RKADD.err?dl=0

Comment: try to connect from command line if you are able...

Comment: Is your bind address correct?

Comment: @WhiteFeather yes it correct

Comment: @ZafarMalik yes I can connect from command line

Comment: 192.168.75.100 is your local ip or mysql db is running on some other machine.

Comment: @ZafarMalik check my edit

Comment: @WhiteFeather check my edit

Answer (score 2):

I reviwed your log.

Up to this point your bind address was localhost (127.0.0.1)

```
160307 15:26:18 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160307 15:26:18 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160307 15:26:18 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
```

Then it seems you changed it in the following 5 minutes:

```
160307 15:31:56 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.75.100'; port: 3306
160307 15:31:56 [Note]   - '192.168.75.100' resolves to '192.168.75.100';
160307 15:31:56 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.75.100'.
```

Then there is another change of bind ip and this time it gives an error!

```
160307 15:35:33 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1597526
160307 15:35:33 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.75.0/24'; port: 3306
160307 15:35:33 [ERROR] Ne peut créer la connexion IP (socket): No such file or directory
160307 15:35:33 [ERROR] Can't start server: cannot resolve hostname!
160307 15:35:33 [ERROR] Aborting
```

You try to start MySql twice with that error, then you change back your bind address:

```
160307 15:37:19 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.75.100'; port: 3306
160307 15:37:19 [Note]   - '192.168.75.100' resolves to '192.168.75.100';
160307 15:37:19 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.75.100'.
```

After that you change again the bind address, maybe without stopping the server you start it again... the server is getting pretty upset:

```
160307 15:43:49 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.75.10'; port: 3306
160307 15:43:49 [Note]   - '192.168.75.10' resolves to '192.168.75.10';
160307 15:43:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.75.10'.
160307 15:43:49 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
160307 15:43:49 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
160307 15:43:49 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It seems you fixed that and you went back again to the previous address:

```
160307 15:44:07 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.75.100'; port: 3306
160307 15:44:07 [Note]   - '192.168.75.100' resolves to '192.168.75.100';
160307 15:44:07 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.75.100'.
```

You make another change to the address!

```
160307 15:45:41 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160307 15:45:41 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160307 15:45:41 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
```

Something went wrong with all those changes and restart as you get:

```
160308 20:41:18 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
160308 20:41:19  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 7481, file name .\mysql-bin.000019
160308 20:41:31  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160308 20:41:32 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1606824
160308 20:41:32 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
160308 20:41:32 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
160308 20:41:32 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
```

From then on you have a lot of crashes, errors and recoveries from abnormal situations or shutdowns, up to the last:

```
160325 11:07:37  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 5190394, file name .\mysql-bin.000035
160325 11:07:37  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160325 11:07:38 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 48295796
160325 11:07:38 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
160325 11:07:38 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
160325 11:07:38 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
160325 11:07:38 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160325 11:07:38 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160325 11:07:38 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
```

It seems you did not treat the server very kindly.

Now the point is the permission you granted to your user, if you change from

```
localhost (127.0.0.1)
```

to:

```
192.168.75.100
```

to:

```
any host (0.0.0.0)
```

you have to be sure that your user has the appropriate permissions, they are a combination of user/host. You need to create multiple users with same id/password and different hosts (127.0.0.1, localhost, any) if you want to have all those possibilities at once.

By the way: your current bind address is any (0.0.0.0) not 192.168.75.100.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your error logs below are my findings-

1. Till when you are able to access your mysql server from phpmyadmin, bind address entry was commented in mysql config file.
2. Someone enable bind address entry (only to localhost) and restarted mysql service. So now you are not able to connect from phpmyadmin.
3. After that someone again commented this entry in config file but did not restart mysqld service.

Solution: As finally now this entry is commented, so you just need to restart mysql service and you will be able to connect.